# Can't install programs on windows 7

Tags: windows, installation

Not sure when this started happening, but I can't seem to install programs anymore on my machine. I ran the Microsoft FixIt tool, which helped people with similar situations, but it didn't find anything wrong with my computer. Does anyone know what else I can try?

Comment: any error messages? Anything juicy in the event logs?

Comment: What sort of event logs should I be looking at?

Comment: well, stuff from around the time you are attempting to install would be a good start.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure where I should be finding these logs

Answer (score 1):

well, I think your pc can be infected with **virus** problem. Boot into **Safe mode** by pressing **F8** during to boot and choose Safe mode. Try if you can install a small+simple software in safe mode. But i suggest you do a **full virus scan** with a good antivirus software.

p/s: the quick way is re-install your windows 7

Hope this help

Comment: I know the quick way, but I don't want to do it unless it has to come to that.